# How to set a special tabstop when open a special file with vim?

Tags: vim

Here is my [vimfiles](https://github.com/mingchaoyan/dotvim).

I write

```
 se tabstop=4
```

in my vimrc. But sometimes I read some project source codes, they use TAB to indent and set tab equals 8 space. So I must

```
:set tabstop=8
```

to make the code indent right.

If I can make sure the path of source code (eg. /home/foo/erlang/), 
 is there a method to make my life better?

I mean to write some code in vimrc, like

```
if file in path "home/foo/erlang"
 then set tabstop=8
end
```

or some other vim settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add that stuff to your own `.vimrc` file then one thing you can do is just `autocmd` file opens to call a function to set things up like you'd like... The docs talk about doing this, see `:help autocmd-patterns`

```
autocmd   BufRead   */home/foo/erlang/*   set tabstop=8
```

I actually have a few autocmds which do "big" setup on filetypes depending on their directory and other attributes. One such might look like this:

```
autocmd BufRead *.txt   call SetUpTextFileBuffer(expand("<afile>:p"))
```

Then that function does path matching and so forth to configure a whole range of options (autoformatting, text width, etc.). Modelines are certainly better if you can insert them but sometimes you're working with others' code and you don't want to leave a huge footprint.

Comment: very nice! It seems the best method!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `.vimrc` file in the directory where you want the settings to apply. It would contain your `tabstop` and other Erlang-specific settings.

```
% cd ~/erlang
% ls
... .vimrc
% vim somefile.erl
```

Vim will automatically see and use the `.vimrc` in `$PWD`. (For this to work, you should have `set exrc` in your `~/.vimrc`). See `:help 'exrc'` for details.

If you don’t want to `cd` and open files from that directory, you can always invoke Vim with an explicit startup file:

```
vim -u /path/to/erlang.vimrc somefile.erl
```

Comment: vim -u will only load /path/to/erlang/.vimrc.  It seems set exrc in ~/.vimrc and have a .vimrc in /path/to/erlang/.vimrc, this method will load ~/.vimrc and /path/to/erlang/.vimrc. It helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) in your file.
(You need to have `set modeline` in your `.vimrc` for this to work.)

In the first or last lines of your file, put the following comment;

```
% vim: tabstop=8:
```

By default, the first and last 5 lines are scanned for modelines.

Comment: I've used this without the %. What in this context does the % mean?

Comment: @Steve     :h modeline.  % just a [text] in this form, you can use whatever text you want. But usually we use the comment char, % is the comment char of Erlang.

Comment: @Roland Smith  it is not a good idea.  Because I do not want to edit the source code of other source open project. Also I do not want to change my  settings of tabstop when coding my own code.